# NextJS error message: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header, next.js

I'm implementing a header from a GatsbyJS project into NextJS project and get the following error message:

"Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead."

When removing the following from the header.jsx it does not provide any error messages:
<MenuButton item={{ icon: "/images/icons/hamburger.svg" }} />

Can you guide me on what I'm doing wrong?

This is my header.jsx file:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Link from "next/link";
import { menuData } from "../../data/menuData";
import MenuButton from "../buttons/MenuButton.jsx";
import Image from "next/image";
import MenuTooltip from "../tooltips/MenuTooltip";

export default function Header() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef();
  const tooltipRef = useRef();

  function handleClick(event) {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (
      ref.current &&
      !ref.current.contains(event.target) &&
      !tooltipRef.current.contains(event.target)
    ) {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Link href="/">
        <Logo>
          <Image
            src="/images/logos/logo.png"
            alt="Logo"
            width={120}
            height={100}
          />
        </Logo>
      </Link>
      <MenuWrapper count={menuData.length} ref={ref}>
        {menuData.map((item, index) => (
          <MenuButton key={index} item={item} />
        ))}
        <HamburgerWrapper onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)}>
          <MenuButton item={{ icon: "/images/icons/hamburger.svg" }} />
        </HamburgerWrapper>
      </MenuWrapper>
      <div ref={tooltipRef}>
        <MenuTooltip isOpen={isOpen} />
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

This is my menuTooltip.jsx file:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { tooltipData } from "../../data/menuData";
import MenuButton from "../buttons/MenuButton";

export default function MenuTooltip(props) {
  const { isOpen } = props;
  return (
    <Wrapper isOpen={isOpen}>
      {tooltipData.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuButton key={index} item={item} />
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

This is my MenuButton.jsx file:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Caption } from "../styles/TextStyles";

export default function MenuButton(props) {
  const { item } = props;
  return (
    <Link href={item.link} onClick={props.onClick} key={props}>
      <MenuItem hasTitle={!item.title ? false : true}>
        <img src={item.icon} />
        {item.title}
      </MenuItem>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

This is my menuData.jsx file:

```js
export const menuData = [
  { title: "Learn", icon: "/images/icons/learner02_dm.svg", link: "/learn" },
  {
    title: "Articles",
    icon: "/images/icons/article_light.svg",
    link: "/articles",
  },
  {
    title: "Community",
    icon: "/images/icons/community_light.svg",
    link: "/community",
  },
  {
    title: "Entrepreneurs",
    icon: "/images/icons/business02_light.svg",
    link: "/entrepreneurs",
  },
];

export const footerMenuData = [
  { title: "Learn", icon: "/images/icons/learner02_dm.svg", link: "/learn" },
  {
    title: "Articles",
    icon: "/images/icons/article_light.svg",
    link: "/articles",
  },
  {
    title: "Community",
    icon: "/images/icons/community_light.svg",
    link: "/community",
  },
  {
    title: "Entrepreneurs",
    icon: "/images/icons/business02_light.svg",
    link: "/entrepreneurs",
  },
  {
    title: "Updates",
    icon: "/images/icons/calendar_light.svg",
    link: "/updates",
  },
  {
    title: "Help",
    icon: "/images/icons/help_light.svg",
    link: "/help",
  },
];

export const tooltipData = [
  { title: "Learn", icon: "/images/icons/learner02_dm.svg", link: "/learn" },
  {
    title: "Articles",
    icon: "/images/icons/article_light.svg",
    link: "/articles",
  },
  {
    title: "Community",
    icon: "/images/icons/community_light.svg",
    link: "/community",
  },
  {
    title: "Entrepreneurs",
    icon: "/images/icons/business02_light.svg",
    link: "/entrepreneurs",
  },
];
```

Comment: the error is pretty clear. it says you need to pass `link` but you're only passing `icon` `<MenuButton item={{ icon: "/images/icons/hamburger.svg" .. missing link . }} />`, is your hamburger button supposed to be a link?

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes about that! It is supposed to be just an icon, which is opening the menuTooltip. How would you implement it instead?

Comment: make a different component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add a tag a in the link like that :

```
<link href....> 
  <a> 
    <image> 
    <p> text </p> 
  </a> 
</link>
```

I often get this error too...

Answer (score 15):

Oh gosh! I was stuck with this problem for so long and finally managed to fix it. While I am happy that the accepted answer worked for you, sadly it didn't for me. So, I am leaving here the fix that I found on the [discussion thread of NextJS's official GitHub repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/21610#discussioncomment-3114351).

**Instead of passing the link key directly into the `Link`'s `href` prop:**

```
<Link href={item.link} {...other props}>...</Link>
```

**Pass it in string literals like this:**

```
<Link href={`${item.link}`} {...other props}>...</Link>
```

You may wrap the children of the `Link` component in a `<a>` tag if you want but that's not required, and mine is working without that. FYI, I had some SVG icons inside the `Link` components that were creating all this fuss. Sigh!

Answer (score 5):

***for anyone else who is migrating from react-router-dom to next.js built-in Link component.***
this error happened to me because I was migrating from react-router-dom to the built-in Link component in Next.js, and I forgot to change the `to=""` property in `<Link></Link>` component to `href=""`

**Wrong ❌**

```
<Link to=""></Link>
```

**Correct ✅**

```
<Link href=""></Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pass it a string like this:**

```
<Link href='your-link-here.com'> YOUR CONTENT HERE </Link>
<Link href='#'> YOUR CONTENT HERE </Link>
```

OR

**Pass it as an object like this:**

```
<Link href={item.link}> YOUR CONTENT HERE </Link>
```